# MySQL Trigger not saving

Tags: mysql, sql

Executing this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_order_insert`
    AFTER INSERT ON `hb_orders` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       UPDATE hb_accounts
       SET hb_accounts.domain = (SELECT companyname FROM hb_client_details
                     WHERE hb_client_details.id = NEW.client_id
                            LIMIT 1)
       WHERE hb_accounts.client_id = NEW.client_id;
    END
```

Results in this:

/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8 */

What am I missing? This should work, shouldn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely trying to add the trigger without changing the delimiter. Since the trigger contains semicolon, you'll have to change the delimiter to something else temporarily;

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `after_order_insert`
    AFTER INSERT ON `hb_orders` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       UPDATE hb_accounts
       SET hb_accounts.domain = (SELECT companyname FROM hb_client_details
                     WHERE hb_client_details.id = NEW.client_id
                            LIMIT 1)
       WHERE hb_accounts.client_id = NEW.client_id;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

[An SQLfiddle with the trigger adding successfully](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93ce8/1). Note that the delimiter is changed in the settings,

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_order_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `hb_orders` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE hb_accounts a
join hb_client_details b on a.client_id = b.id and b.id = new.client_id
set a.domain = b.companyname;
```